# Can I add keyevents to a timer in VB.NET

Tags: winforms, timer

Is it possible that I can add keyevents in my timer. I know I can add mouse events but when I try to run the following code in the timer SUB: if e.keycode keys.E then msgbox.show("Bla bla bla") end if. It says you can only add tick events. Thanks for your time.

,,,,Public Class Form2

```
Private Sub Form2_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.W Then
        W.BackColor = Color.White
    End If
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.S Then
        Label2.BackColor = Color.White
    End If
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then
        Label1.BackColor = Color.White
    End If
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.D Then
        Label3.BackColor = Color.White
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form2_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyUp
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.W Then
        W.BackColor = Color.Gray

    End If
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.S Then
        Label2.BackColor = Color.Gray
    End If
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then
        Label1.BackColor = Color.Gray
    End If
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.D Then
        Label3.BackColor = Color.Gray
    End If
End Sub
'just some stuff

Private Sub Form2_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseDown
    If Button.MouseButtons = MouseButtons.Left Then
        Label4.BackColor = Color.White
    End If
    If Button.MouseButtons = MouseButtons.Right Then
        Label5.BackColor = Color.White
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form2_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseUp
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        Label4.BackColor = Color.Gray

    End If
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then
        Label5.BackColor = Color.Gray
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.TopMost = True
    Timer1.Start()


End Sub
'my problem
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.W Then
        W.BackColor = Color.White

    End If

End Sub
```

End Class,,,,,

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: Ok it is kind o messy so here

Comment: Just save the last state of the mouse as member variable in your form class and check it and reset in the timer function.

Comment: Thanks that helped. But with my mouse only. By any chance can you do the same with the keyboard

Comment: where is the issue with keyboard? if you have done some progress with the code, i recommend updating the question with the latest code.

Comment: My issue is I can’t actively use this program while I am on another application. I found if I did the following code In the timer sub the mouse buttons would register. The code is:     If mousebuttons = mousebuttons.Left then label1.backcolor = color.white end if. But how can I add if a specific key gets pressed while the timer is running the backcolor of the label goes white.